# How to sort extracted values according to element conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, gbxml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gbXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gbxml.org/schema xsi.xsd"xmlns="http://www.gbxml.org/schema"
 temperatureUnit="C" lengthUnit="Meters" areaUnit="SquareMeters"volumeUnit="CubicMeters"
useSIUnitsForResults="true" version="0.37">

<Pared id="Pa-1" paredType="Shade">     
<Name>P-S-1</Name>
<Order>
    <Direction>0.000000</Direction>
    <Angle>90.000000</Angle>
    <Height>3.657818</Height>
    <Width>15.200000</Width>
</Order>
</Pared>
<Pared id="Pa-2" paredType="Shade">     
    <Name>P-S-2</Name>
    <Order>
        <Direction>90.000000</Direction>
        <Angle>90.000000</Angle>
        <Height>2.598076</Height>
        <Width>14.200000</Width>
    </Order>
</Pared>
</gbXML>
```

I want to extract the "Height" and "Width" values of each "Pared id" and sort them out according to the "Direction" and "Angle" values. For example, in "Pared id= "Pa-1", if the "Direction"= 0.000000 AND the "Angle"= 90.000000, then the order of the extracted values of Width and Height should be:

```
(Width, 0.00)
(Width, Height)
(0.00, Height)
(0.00, 0.00)
```

I am new to XSLT and I know how to select the values of Width and Height with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"   xmlns:gb="http://www.gbxml.org/schema">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:template match= "gb:Pared">
<xsl:value-of select="gb:Order/gb:Height/>
```

But I do not know how to sort them manually like I mentioned before. I will really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

I want the following Output (applying the conditions I mentioned before):

From Pared id="Pa-1:

```
(15.200000, 0.000000)
(15.200000, 3.657818)
(0.000000, 3.657818)
(0.000000, 0.000000)
```

From Pared id="Pa-2:

```
(0.000000, 0.000000)
(14.200000, 0.000000)
(14.200000, 2.598076)
(0.000000, 2.598076)
```

Think of it as wall coordinates X,Y. The two walls cannot have the same coordinates and the values of height and width act like the coordinate values. According to the "Direction" and the "Angle" of the wall is how those coordinates are paired.
You have 0.000 coordinate values because of the 4 X, Y points that describe that wall. Therefore, Pa-1 and Pa-2 cannot have the same coordinates but they might be joined at one coordinate. Like if have two walls than form a L shape, 0.00, 0.00 can be the right bottom coordinate of Pa-1, but if the case of Pa-2, 0.00, 0.00 is the left bottom coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand correctly. The following XSL, outputs the width and height values, grouped by the Pared section, which is ordered by Direction then Angle (numeric, ascending).

Just be careful, in your XML example, I had to separate some of the `gbXML`'s attributes with a space (otherwise it's not valid XML).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
 xmlns:ns0="http://www.gbxml.org/schema">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select='//ns0:Pared' >
            <xsl:sort select=".//ns0:Direction" data-type='number' order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select=".//ns0:Angle"     data-type='number' order="ascending"/>
-- Pared: <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
(<xsl:value-of select=".//ns0:Width" />,0.00)
(<xsl:value-of select=".//ns0:Width" />,<xsl:value-of select=".//ns0:Height" />)
(0.00,<xsl:value-of select=".//ns0:Height" />)
(0.00,0.00)
</xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives

```
-- Pared: Pa-1
(15.200000,0.00)
(15.200000,3.657818)
(0.00,3.657818)
(0.00,0.00)

-- Pared: Pa-2
(14.200000,0.00)
(14.200000,2.598076)
(0.00,2.598076)
(0.00,0.00)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I only copy part of the XML file that's why. Your code works when it's only the two "Pared" elements that I have there. In the complete XML file I have more "Pared" elements than that and some of them have the same "Direction" and "Angle" values but different "Height" and "Width" values. I did not put all the 22 Pared elements I have because I thought was going to be really confusing to understand what I wanted. Your code helps a lot since I have an idea now, just have to solve the problems I mentioned before. Thank you again!